# JQuery Ajax POST to Web API returning 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, asp.net-web-api

So I have a jquery ajax request like this:

```
    function createLokiAccount(someurl) {
    var d = {"Jurisdiction":17}

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"http://myserver:111/Api/V1/Customers/CreateCustomer/",
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){alert(data);},
                failure: function(errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });
    }
```

This is hitting my web api which is basically:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public CreateCustomer.Response CreateCustomer(CreateCustomer.Request request)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    ...
```

Which when I call it in Chrome gives me:

```
OPTIONS http://myserver:111/Api/V1/Customers/CreateCustomer/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I do the POST request from Fiddler it includes "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in the response header as it should, which would suggest the API is configured correctly, yet the (from Fiddler) the jquery request looks like:

OPTIONS http://myserver:111/Api/V1/Customers/CreateCustomer/ HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver:111
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:6500
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:6500/Home/Replication?interval=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,it-IT;q=0.4,it;q=0.2

So why is my POST request getting turned into an OPTIONS request?

Comment: Are you making ajax request from http://localhost:6500 to API running on  http://myserver:111?

Comment: Yes I am. GET requests seem to work fine, it's just the POST that isn't doing what I'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're adding only one header, but there is at least three of them you needed:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"

"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept"
```

Secondly, in case if you need CORS only for one method in certain controller, the way you're adding headers is ok. But in common it's not right.

ASP.NET 5 with Web API 2 offers [CORS library](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

But if you're using Web API, I can offer solution (not truly proper, but working). Just add (in Global.asax) to every request required headers

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
```